# Form posting in MVC4 using AJAX - partialview and ModelState.IsValid and modalbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using ASP.NET MVC4 to create an application and I'm facing an issue regarding AJAX and partial views.

Right now, I have a view rendering :

- a partial view (called `_createUser`) which is a modalbox containing a Form to create a user in my application (rendered via `@{Html.RenderPartial("_createUser");}`)
- a partial action (called `ListUsers`) which is an action that simply renders users currently registered in my application (rendered via `@{Html.RenderAction("users");}` in an html table

When the user clicks a button, the modal box contained in `_createUser` is displayed via jquery so the user can type informations about a new user. When he clicks on a button in the modal box, the form is submitted via AJAX to an action in my controller which checks `ModelState.IsValid`.

And this is where I'm stuck because I don't know what is the correct way of handling success/error with partial view using jquery because if the model is correct and the registration is correct, I want to refresh only the list of users.
Is the model is not valid, I want to refresh the modal box with errors raised by the `ModelState`.

My action is :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register( RegisterModel model )
    {
        if( ModelState.IsValid )
        {
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount( model.UserName, model.Password );
                WebSecurity.Login( model.UserName, model.Password );

                ViewBag.CreateUserSucceded = true;

                return RedirectToAction( "ListUsers" );
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError( "", ErrorCodeToString( e.StatusCode ) );
            }
        }

        return PartialView( "_createUser", model );
    }
```

My jquery is pretty simple too :

```
function SubmitCreateUserForm() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Register")',
        data: $("#createUserForm").serialize(),
        success: function (result, status, jqXHR) {
            ????
        }
    });
}
```

I think the correct way should be to use JSON and, instead of returning and `ActionResult`, I should return some JSON containing for a status field and the data related to my users list or validation errors and using the status field to know which part of my main view must be updated.
By I really don't know how to mix JSON result and a razor view. Any clue?

**Updated (I can't answer my own question right now or I have to wait 8 hours).**

Ok, I ended up using what I found in this link http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/05/15/asp-net-mvc-render-partial-view-to-string/

It's pretty straightforward and does the job really well!

Comment: You can use `ActionResult` and return JSON... `return Json(model);` then you'll need to build html in your success handler and insert into a div you defined in your Razor view.

Comment: By doing so, I'm going to loose advantages of `RenderPartial`, that is to say the natural ability of MVC to do the html construction from a model, don't you think?

Comment: Yes, with JSON you'd build html on the client side which would mean you can't take advantage of a strongly-typed PartialView.

Comment: Here's post that addresses validation with JSON: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690967/asp-net-mvc-3-json-model-binding-and-server-side-model-validation-mixed-with-cli

Comment: Well, I updated my question with an answer (I can't answer my own question right now, I'm too young!)